# Eclipse crashing on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, javaw

Whenever I try to start Eclipse on Linux, it briefly opens up, then crashes with the following error:

```
VM terminated. Exit code=160
/opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/jdk/jre/bin/javaw
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xss2048k
-Xmaxf0.1
-Xminf0.05
-Xmx1024m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.javamodelcache.ratio=0.0625
-Dorg.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize=25000000
-jar /opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122    _1400.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library
/opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345/eclipse_1310.so
-startup
/opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-exitdata 1148009
-install /opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0
-vm /opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/jdk/jre/bin/javaw
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xss2048k
-Xmaxf0.1
-Xminf0.05
-Xmx1024m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.javamodelcache.ratio=0.0625
-Dorg.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize=25000000
-jar
/opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
```

I have checked to make sure the Java and Eclipse are both 32-bit installations.

From java -version:

```
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32 jvmxi3260sr9-20110726_87
```

From eclipse.ini:

```
--launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
```

What else could I be missing?

Comment: @Bela I have 1715 MB free. Total is 5963 MB.

Comment: ok thanks, then it can't be an issue, I google around it a bit, this bugreport complains about IBM VM (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=116730). Firstly, do you have gtk installed? Secondly, could you please try to start Eclipse with this command 'eclipse -vmargs -Dosgi.locking=none -Xnojit', the bugreport says it solved an other problem.

Comment: @BelaVizer, thanks for your response. In my plugins directory, I do have eclipse_1310.so present in the directory `/opt/ibm/IntegrationDesigner/v8.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345`

Comment: I tried starting Eclipse with the command you mentioned, and got a bit different of an error after the crash. JVM terminated. Exit code=160. Also mentioned org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar... Maybe I need to reinstall the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing WebSphere Integration Designer, and I no longer encountered the issues. Thanks for the suggestions in the comments, everyone. :)